# Grails 2.1.1. exits with error "bad"

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy, jetty

I'm running a grails application (grails 2.1.1) on a debian server. The application starts and runs nicely until it stops with nothing more than the word "bad" on the terminal. No errors, no stacktraces are reported. Has anybody ever encountered this issue? What does it mean?

The server is rather big (32gb ram and, 128gb encrypted SSD, 8 cores) so I doubt the application runs out of resources.

As of plugins, I only use the pre-packaged plugins and make use of caching (standard RAM caching of controller + ehcache).

I've tried both, "grails prod run-app", "grails prod run-war", so it happens on Jetty and Tomcat respectively.

I'd greatly appreciate help or hints.

Comment: grails 2.2.1? do you mean 2.1.1?

Comment: right, sorry I mean 2.1.1, edited

Comment: i remember this error, and i think it was due to a plugin, what is the list of plugins for your app?

Comment: list of plugins: cache 1.0.0, database-migration 1.1, hibernate 2.1.1, jquery 1.7.2, resources 1.1.6, tomcat 2.1.1, webxml 1.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that you are using the "grails" command to run the app in production? You should deploy to Tomcat (or Jetty or some other "appserver")

This is probably where the "bad" gets printed from:
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-tomcat/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/IsolatedWarTomcatServer.groovy#L92

Perhaps the default port is reserved. Try running grails on another port. Add "grails.server.port.http=8181" to BuildConfig.groovy to start http on port 8181.

Comment: you can use the http://grails.org/plugin/standalone plugin to run grails on an embedded tomcat (or jetty).

Comment: the standalone tip was super, thank you a lot! it works now perfectly. the run-war should be removed from grails if it fails so badly.

Comment: I just ran into this with Grails 2.2.4. Here's a link to the relevant source: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/v2.2.4/grails-plugin-tomcat/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/tomcat/IsolatedWarTomcatServer.groovy#L92